# SQL REPLACE in Column1 and UPDATE in Column 2 at the same time

Tags: regex, sqlite, replace, sql-update, pattern-matching

I have a SQLite database with 2 columns CITY / YEAR like this. CITY has actually the city and the year in one column (this is intended).

```
   1. Paris-2018               / 2018
   2. Berlin-2018              / 2018
   3. Rome-2018] [wrong data   / g Data
   4. Stockholm-2019           / 2019
   6. La-Paz-2018              / 2019
   5. London-2018] [wrong data / g Data
```

In column CITY ans YEAR 9% of the rows have crap data which always starts with "] [....." after the correct string in CITY and just crap data in YEAR. I want to remove "] [....." from all affected rows in CITY AND at the same time set column YEAR for those rows to the string after the last "-" in CITY string.

How could I do that? The result should look like this:

```
   1. Paris-2018               / 2018
   2. Berlin-2018              / 2018
   3. Rome-2018                / 2018
   4. Stockholm-2019           / 2019
   6. La-Paz-2018              / 2019
   5. London-2018              / 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it with just substr/instr?

The corrected city/year would be something like `substr(cityyear,1,instr(cityyear,']')-1)`.

The corrected year would be something like `substr(cityyear,instr(cityyear,'-2') +1,4)` (assuming all years in this century). If there are years in the other centuries, you could use CASE statement(s).

(And only update rows that contain `]`, perhaps with `where instr(cityyear,']') > 0`)

Answer (score 0):

You must apply conditional update, since there are clean and not clean values in the column `city`:

```
update tablename
set 
  city = case 
           when instr(city,']') > 0 then substr(city, 1, instr(city, ']') - 1)
           else city
         end, 
  year = case 
           when instr(city,']') > 0 then substr(city, instr(city,']') - 4, 4)
           else substr(city, length(city) - 3, 4)
         end;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ex3boZanQdjdzxvPPKpVXu/0)

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks. As I understand this is static to 4 chars of the YEAR.
But how would you make the substition dynamic? Imagine the string in CITY is not "Paris-2008" but "Paris-SomeThing1", "London-WayDifferentSomething", "Berlin-EvenLongerSomething". And I want to put the string after the "-" into the other Column?

Comment: Then use `substr(city, instr(city, '-') + 1)`. This returns the part of city starting right after the `-` until the end.

Comment: Thanks again. Though this does not work for cities which have more than one "-" in thier name like 'La-Paz-Something1'. What I get then is "Paz-Something1' because it takes the first '-'. What I need here it to take the _last_ "-" occurance though. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I checked the fiddle demo, The 'substr(city, length(city) - 3, 4)' works only for static sizes of substrings. In this example -3 is static and 4 is static too. What I have now is:

aaaaa-bbb-cccc-dddd-eeeee-wwwwwww-gggg. Where the substrings between "-" are of dynamic length. And I want to extract only the 'ggggg' (which can be of 1-n chars long in intself), the string after the last "-". 
So I cannot use concrete numbers like -3 or +4. Because 'gggg' can be of size 5 or 10

Comment: This answer is about the question you posted. If you have another question you can post a new one and **not in the comments**.

Comment: Sure, as you wish. Though its the same question, just a more abstract version of it. Now you dont have a static amount of chars (exactly 4 - as in YEAR, but now you have a dynamic amount of chars and a dynamic amount of '-* in a string. Not sure if it is worth another question. It is just an abstraction which imho very well belongs here.

Comment: You posted a question and sample data and you got **a working answer** for these.